# Which one is better for validation email tag vs regex vs input type?

Tags: html, regex, validation, email

pls help me to select the best solution for email validation, i found 3 options:

1, with pattern

```
<input type="email" id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2, 4}$">
```

2, type="text" and email tag

```
<input type="text" id="email" email>
```

3, type="email" and email tag

```
<input type="email" id="email">
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ancient browsers (IE9 and before) don't support the `type="email"` attribute, but nowadays, that's probably not a concern, given that many sites are dropping support for IE11.

As [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Validation):

> Browsers that support the email input type automatically provide validation to ensure that only text that matches the standard format for Internet e-mail addresses is entered into the input box. Browsers that implement the specification should be using an algorithm equivalent to the following regular expression:
>
> ```
> /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
> ```

It's not a completely trivial pattern. Also, your current pattern `{2, 4}` will only match TLDs with 2 to 4 characters, but there are some TLDs with more.

The email attribute (eg, the `email` before the `>` in `<input type="text" id="email" email>`) doesn't look to serve any purpose.

If you're not intending to support ancient obsolete browsers, it's probably easiest to just use `type="email"` and let the browser conform to the specification, rather than try to re-implement some (possibly non-spec-compliant) version yourself.

```
<input type="email">
```

Keep in mind that this is *frontend* validation only, but clients may run whatever code they want on the frontend - if you want to make sure the email your server processes is valid, make sure to validate it on the backend too.

Answer (score 1):

The regEXP (1st method) ids the best in my opinion. it's similar to 3rd one but is has one benefit:

you couls have a customized and your own validation message with custom style and it helps your website / app look more beautiful and user friendly

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is certainly the most complete, the others only check if there is one '@' in the input

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)